# Comment traduire « However little I may remember »?

Tags: traduction, formulation

Je me demande si le choix suivant est le bon ?

- (Aussi) peu dont je (ne) me souvien(ne) …?

Veuillez en proposer d’autres si celui-ci ne convient pas.

La phrase en anglais peut être aussi écrite de la façon suivante :  « Little as I may remember, …».

Merci d’avance

Comment: It seems that you can't  write "However little may I"; see this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=however+little+may+I%2CHowever+little+I+may&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHowever%20little%20I%20may%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CHowever%20little%20I%20may%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: "However little may I remember" or "Little as I may remember" just don't mean anything in English . *Aussi peu dont je me souvienne..* est bizarre mais peut-être possible si tu donnais un contexte. Par ailleurs tu demandes  « lequel des choix suivants est le bon ? » mais il n'y a pas de choix vu que tu ne donnes qu'une seule possibilité. *Aussi peu dont je me souvienne* in English would be  "as little as I remember"

Comment: @LPH Oh, sorry yeah I guess my English was a bit off there. I’ll fix it.

Comment: @None The context would be something like, « My childhood, however little I may remember of it, plays a large role in my current confidence ».

Comment: You should include **all** necessary details in the question.  "Little as I may remember is just not good English ... I think you mean "as far as I remember" .

Comment: ... "du peu que je me souvienne" ou "du peu dont je me souvienne" ont ete mes "premieres" pensees sur juste "however little I may remember", mais faudrait plus de "Contexte"..., ya deja une Nuance entre "que" et "dont" selon le Contexte... (Mais je trouve la Formulation en anglais deja un shouyah bizarre, just saying, c'est pas du "Native"...)

Comment: ***However little I may remember*** **is 100% correct in English**. However little I may [have etc.]. Par contre, une phrase en entier serait mieux. **However little I may remember him, what I do remember is that he was a nice fellow.

Comment: Et "**little as I remember [etc.]**" aussi. Mais cela veut dire autre chose que l'autre expression. Il faut des phrases complètes, en tout cas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Une forme idiomatique approchante est :

> Pour autant que je m'en souvienne.

Une traduction plus proche, mais non attestée serait :

> Quelque peu que je m'en souvienne.

Voici une rare occurrence d'un usage proche:

> *Seulement, à Croisset, j’ai mon canot et le jardin, et puis je suis plus loin des Rouennais qui, quelque peu que je les fréquente, me pèsent aux épaules d’une façon dont les compatriotes sont seuls capables.* Flaubert, *Correspondances*, 1845.

<s>Une recherche monte que l'anglais ***however little I may**...* est une tournure rare et désuète, ce qui est certainement aussi le cas de « **quelque peu que je**... ».</s>

*Quelque peu que je m'en souvienne* est peut-être trop littéraire et désuet. Voici une forme plus courante :

> Pour peu que je m'en souvienne.

Comment: Mais non, dans le langage parlé, c'est commun. Et puis pour le langage parlé, les moyens de recherche ne sont pas très fiable. "However little I may [verb]" n'est ni rare ni désuèt.

Comment: @Lambie Dont acte.

Answer (score 4):

None of the forms considered are correct.

- peu dont je  me souvien(ne) …? *not correct*
- Aussi peu dont je  me souvien(ne) …? *not correct*
- Aussi peu dont je ne me souvien(ne) …? *not correct*

The following construction is one way to put that.

- Bien que je me souvienne de peu…
- My childhood, however little I may remember of it, plays a large role in my current confidence.
  *Mon enfance, bien que je m'en souvienne peu, joue un rôle important dans mon assurance.*

Comment: Oui, pour la phrase traduite: bien que je m'en souvienne peu, mais l'anglais serait: **However little I may remember it or of it**.